# Toolbar back arrow icon is not visible on Ionic 4

Tags: ionic4

```
<ion-toolbar color="dark">
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-menu-button></ion-menu-button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-title>
      Home
    </ion-title>
</ion-toolbar>
```

Menu icon is not visible in the above ionic4 code

Answer (score 2):

You need to add it explicitly in Ionic 4:

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar color="dark">
        <ion-buttons slot="start">
            <ion-menu-button autoHide="true"></ion-menu-button>
            <ion-back-button [defaultHref]="defaultHref"></ion-back-button>
        </ion-buttons>
        <ion-title>Home</ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```

And you can set a default path for when no history exist: `defaultHref = '/some/route/';`

If this doesn't work, double check that your `angular.json` config includes this:

```
{
    "assets": [
        {
            "glob": "**/*",
            "input": "src/assets",
            "output": "assets"
        },
        {
            "glob": "**/*.svg",
            "input": "node_modules/ionicons/dist/ionicons/svg",
            "output": "./svg"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for giving reply, I have used your code, still menu Icon not visible, I am getting error (GET 192.168.56.1:8100/svg/md-menu.svg 404 (Not Found)) on chrome console

Comment: Have you installed Ionicons?

Comment: As per the github installation instructions(https://github.com/ionic-team/ionicons), If you're using Ionic Framework, Ionicons is packaged by default, so no installation is necessary. Want to use Ionicons without Ionic Framework? Place the following <script> near the end of your page, right before the closing tag, to enable them.

<script src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@4.2.2/dist/ionicons.js"></script>

Comment: Now I am getting Menu icons, Arrow back icons after adding <script src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@4.2.2/dist/ionicons.js"></script> in index.html

Comment: I am using Ionic framework only, but i don't know why icons are not visible, after adding script tag in index.html I am able to see icons

Comment: Do you have ionicons correctly specified in your angular.json? I updated my original post.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188660/discussion-between-mohan-and-remi-sture).

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the color of back button, as you are giving color dark to toolbar, it might be the case it got hidden because of that.

Comment: Thanks for giving reply, I tried to change the color, still menu is not visible, I am getting error  (GET http://192.168.56.1:8100/svg/md-menu.svg 404 (Not Found)) on chrome console

Comment: Now I am getting Menu icons, Arrow back icons after adding <script src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@4.2.2/dist/ionicons.js"></script> in index.html